# SqlDependency code listening to inserts/update in a table from windows service

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services, sqldependency

my SqlDependency code is listening to inserts/update in a table from windows service and when i start the service then it works for next 2/3 days and after that it stopped working.

here i am pasting my full code.

```
public partial class PartIndexer : ServiceBase
    {
        static string connectionString = "MyConnection String;Pooling=true;Connect Timeout=20;";
        SqlDependency dep;

        public PartIndexer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region OnStart
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
            RegisterNotification();
            MailNotify("STARTED");
        }
        #endregion

        #region RegisterNotification
        /// <summary>
        /// RegisterNotification
        /// this is main routine which will monitor data change in ContentChangeLog table
        /// </summary>
        private void RegisterNotification()
        {
            string tmpdata = "";
            //eventLog1.WriteEntry("RegisterNotification invoked"); 

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ActivityDate FROM [bba-reman].ContentChangeLog";
                    dep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
                    dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDataChange);
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            if (dr[0] != DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                tmpdata = dr[0].ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    dr.Dispose();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                //SqlDependency.Stop(connStr);
            }

        }
        #endregion

        #region OnDataChange
        /// <summary>
        /// OnDataChange
        /// OnDataChange will fire when after data change found in ContentChangeLog table
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void OnDataChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDependency dep = sender as SqlDependency;
            dep.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDataChange);
            SendMailNotification();
            RegisterNotification();
        }
         #endregion

        #region StartIndex
        /// <summary>
        /// StartIndex
        /// this routine will call web service in bba reman website which will invoke routine to re-index data
        /// </summary>
        void SendMailNotification()
        {
            // does some job

        }
        #endregion

        #region MailNotify
        /// <summary>
        /// MailNotify
        /// fire mail when apps start & exit
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strStatus"></param>
        void MailNotify(string strStatus)
        {
            if (strStatus == "STARTED")
            {
                var template = new MailTemplate()
                    .WithBody("HI,<br><br>Part Indexer Started Date " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())
                    .WithSubject("Part Indexer Started")
                    .WithSender("xxxxx")
                    .WithRecepient("xxxx")
                    .Send();
            }
            else if (strStatus == "STOPPED")
            {
                var template = new MailTemplate()
                    .WithBody("HI,<br><br>Part Indexer stopped Date " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())
                    .WithSubject("Part Indexer Stopped")
                    .WithSender("xxx")
                    .WithRecepient("xxx")
                    .Send();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region OnStop
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
            MailNotify("STOPPED");
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

i saw another guy face the same problem from this url [SqlDependency error after a long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22319761/sqldependency-error-after-a-long-time?lq=1)

he said timeout error occur. as per his suggestion i change my code bit like

```
void OnDataChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            ((SqlDependency)sender).OnChange -= OnDataChange;
            //SqlDependency dep = sender as SqlDependency;
            //dep.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDataChange);

            if (e.Source == SqlNotificationSource.Timeout)
            {
                // just restart notification
                RegisterNotification();
                return;
            }
            else if (e.Source != SqlNotificationSource.Data)
            {
                ReStartService();
            }

            SendMailNotification();
            RegisterNotification();
        }
```

### just see this line of code

```
 if (e.Source == SqlNotificationSource.Timeout)
                {
                    // just restart notification
                    RegisterNotification();
                    return;
                }
                else if (e.Source != SqlNotificationSource.Data)
                {
                    Environment.Exit(1);
                }
```

if timeout occur then i am calling RegisterNotification() function again.
i wrote these line after reading that url but not sure what the above line will do?

so just guide me am i on right track? please help me make my apps bug free so it can listen for long without any problem. thanks

Comment: What options have you set on the recovery tab of your service?

Comment: @Donal : not clear what you try to ask?

Comment: @Donal: i have not set any recovery option for my service just default setting is there. default setting is : First Failure -- Restart the service. if i stop my service instead of restart does my service will start again?

Comment: the recovery tab is only used in the event of a failure in your service - not if you shut it down manually.

Comment: The problem with SQLDependency is that it only allows a handful of requests, I've SQLDependencies for a Monitoring application, but it proved to be to error prone to be successful, i think microsoft says it only allowed 10 "dependencies" at once, and then it resets - the problem being closing the connection i believe

Answer (score 1):

### Take the full code.

```
#region all using
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
#endregion

namespace PartIndexerService
{
    public partial class PartIndexer : ServiceBase
    {
        static string connectionString = "server=sql08-2.orcsweb.com;uid=bba-reman;password=_bba_1227_kol;database=BBAreman;Pooling=true;Connect Timeout=20;";
        SqlDependency dep;

        public PartIndexer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region OnStart
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            RegisterNotification();
            MailNotify("STARTED");
        }
        #endregion

        #region RegisterNotification
        /// <summary>
        /// RegisterNotification
        /// this is main routine which will monitor data change in ContentChangeLog table
        /// </summary>
        private void RegisterNotification()
        {
            string tmpdata = "";
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ActivityDate FROM [bba-reman].ContentChangeLog";
                    dep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
                    dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDataChange);
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            if (dr[0] != DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                tmpdata = dr[0].ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    dr.Dispose();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                //SqlDependency.Stop(connStr);
            }

        }
        #endregion

        public void ReStartService()
        {
            ServiceController service = new ServiceController("PartIndexer");

            if ((service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)) || (service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)))
            {
                service.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                service.Stop();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
                service.Start();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
            }
        }

        #region OnDataChange
        /// <summary>
        /// OnDataChange
        /// OnDataChange will fire when after data change found in ContentChangeLog table
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void OnDataChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            ((SqlDependency)sender).OnChange -= OnDataChange;

            if (e.Source == SqlNotificationSource.Timeout)
            {
                var template = new MailTemplate()
                    .WithBody("HI,<br><br>Part Indexer Service Exception Timeout occur " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())
                    .WithSubject("Part Indexer Service Exception Timeout occur")
                    .WithSender("bbasupport@bba-reman.com")
                    .WithRecepient("tridip@bba-reman.com")
                    .Send();
                RegisterNotification();
                return;
            }
            else if (e.Source != SqlNotificationSource.Data)
            {
                var template = new MailTemplate()
                    .WithBody("HI,<br><br>Part Indexer Service Exception SqlNotificationSource.Data " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())
                    .WithSubject("Part Indexer Service Exception SqlNotificationSource.Data")
                    .WithSender("bbasupport@bba-reman.com")
                    .WithRecepient("tridip@bba-reman.com")
                    .Send();

                Environment.Exit(1);
            }

            StartIndex();
            RegisterNotification();
        }
         #endregion

        #region StartIndex
        /// <summary>
        /// StartIndex
        /// this routine will call web service in bba reman website which will invoke routine to re-index data
        /// </summary>
        void StartIndex()
        {
            //eventLog1.WriteEntry("Web Service called start for indexing data"); 

            PartIndexerWS.AuthHeader oAuth = new PartIndexerWS.AuthHeader();
            oAuth.Username = "Admin";
            oAuth.Password = "Admin";

            PartIndexerWS.SearchDataIndex DataIndex = new PartIndexerWS.SearchDataIndex();
            DataIndex.AuthHeaderValue = oAuth;
            try
            {
                DataIndex.StartIndex();
                //eventLog1.WriteEntry("Web Service called stop for indexing data"); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                //eventLog1.WriteEntry("Web Service call error "+ex.Message.ToString()); 

            }

        }
        #endregion

        #region MailNotify
        /// <summary>
        /// MailNotify
        /// fire mail when apps start & exit
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strStatus"></param>
        void MailNotify(string strStatus)
        {
            if (strStatus == "STARTED")
            {
                var template = new MailTemplate()
                    .WithBody("HI,<br><br>Part Indexer Started Date " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())
                    .WithSubject("Part Indexer Started")
                    .WithSender("bbasupport@bba-reman.com")
                    .WithRecepient("tridip@bba-reman.com")
                    .Send();
                //eventLog1.WriteEntry("mail fired "); 

            }
            else if (strStatus == "STOPPED")
            {
                var template = new MailTemplate()
                    .WithBody("HI,<br><br>Part Indexer stopped Date " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())
                    .WithSubject("Part Indexer Stopped")
                    .WithSender("bbasupport@bba-reman.com")
                    .WithRecepient("tridip@bba-reman.com")
                    .Send();
                //eventLog1.WriteEntry("mail fired "); 
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region OnStop
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
            MailNotify("STOPPED");
            //eventLog1.WriteEntry("Part Indexer stopped Date : " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()); 

        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```